# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in c using linux - special case

Tags: c, linux

I am basically trying to create a log file which has date and time as its name. This is my code

```
     char logger [500];

     time_t time1;
     struct tm * timeinfo; 
     time (&time1);
     timeinfo = localtime (&time1);
     sprintf(logger, "TestTreiber_%d%d%d%d%d%d.log",timeinfo->tm_year+1900,timeinfo->tm_mon+1,timeinfo->tm_mday,timeinfo->tm_hour,timeinfo->tm_min,timeinfo->tm_sec);

     printf("All logging during this test is done in : %s",logger);

     sprintf(logger, "prot/%s",logger);//STEP 1: I encounter the error here

     FILE *logFile;
     logFile= fopen(logger,"w");
```

Without the step 1 every thing worked fine. It created a log file with the name I wanted in the same folder where my program is. But when I add step 1 into the mix it gives me this error.

```
Segmentation Fault (core dumped)
```

I am new to Linux but I know it has something to do with memory so I increased the memory allocated to logger[500] (it was earlier 255 which worked fine). But I can't seem to solve this problem. prot folder does exist in the directory I am running this. Please help!

PS Sorry about wrong usage of capital letters, I am using a German Keyboard.

Comment: You can't `sprintf` a string to itself, which you do in `sprintf(logger, "prot/%s",logger)`.

Comment: plus replace sprintf with snprintf this is much safer

Comment: @user1034749 I did that but still same error.

Comment: @ITguy "I did that", you did what?

Comment: @LBesancon what user1034749 asked me to do changing sprintf to snprintf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not do this in your code,

```
sprintf(logger, "prot/%s",logger);
```

Quoting from the `man` page of [sprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf),

> Some programs imprudently rely on code such as the following,
>
> `sprintf(buf, "%s some further text", buf);`
>
> to  append  text  to  `buf`.   However, the standards explicitly note that the results are undefined if `source` and `destination` buffers overlap when calling sprintf(), snprintf(), vsprintf(), and vsnprintf().  Depending on the version of gcc used, and the compiler options employed, calls such as the above will not produce the expected results.

Comment: @ITguy My pleasure :)

Answer (score 2):

As others have told you, the destination buffer and string arguments of `sprintf` must not overlap.

You construct the basename first, print it and then want to prepend the path to it. You can use two different buffers for basename and path, but you could also construct the whole path at once and extract the basename of the path with `basename` from `<libgen.h>` for printing:

```
const char *prefix = "prot";
char logger [500];

time_t time1 = time(NULL);
struct tm *ti = localtime (&time1);

snprintf(logger, sizeof(logger), 
    "%s/TestTreiber_%d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d.log", prefix, 
    ti->tm_year + 1900, ti->tm_mon + 1, ti->tm_mday,
    ti->tm_hour, ti->tm_min, ti->tm_sec);

printf("Logger is '%s'.\n", basename(logger));
printf("(Full path is '%s'.)\n", logger);
```

(You should make the output of all fields except the year 2 digits wide and pad it with zeros with the `%02d` format, so that the file name is is unambiguous.)

Answer (score 1):

So first change `sprintf()` to `snprintf()` but also you have to change the arguments you give to the function. Indeed the source and the destination have to be different. I guess it gives undefined behaviour if they're not.

So do something like this:

```
sprintf(newlogger, "prot/%s",logger);
```